# Should derogatory terms for software be edited away by others?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

Should derogatory terms for software such as "Internet Exploder" be edited by others? I know that such terms are generally discouraged, but would editing them away be seen as "disrespecting the author"?

**Background:** I came across the use of [Internet Exploder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon/2399940#2399940), and I'm wondering whether to edit or just leave a comment.

Comment: If this become the community consensus I think we should create an exception for Internet Explorer, lol

Comment: I'm sure Jeff will clean that up himself, since he's in Bill Gates' pocket, you know.

Comment: Well, in this *specific* case - I just followed the link - I'm pretty sure the derogatory term stems from man-weeks lost to implementing compatibility measures more than all-out hatred of commercial software, which makes it kind of okay in my eyes :)

Answer (score 7):

You should do both.

Leave a comment noting your approval, and edit in the missing M$ prefix...

Comment: Heh, speaking of....

Comment: Don't forget to go on a tirade about how they are a greedy corporation only out to make money. And try to use the terms "fat cats" and "cronies".

Answer (score 5):

Consider the purpose of StackOverflow. It is supposed to become *the* repository for information regarding technical problems and solutions. For that reason we would expect(enforce) a certain level of professionalism.

It's also important to consider the audience. While some people may think it's funny, it doesn't make them *more* likely to trust the question or the answer. In fact, it makes everything on the page seem more juvenile.

Edit out the offending line, leave a comment indicating that insults are never appropriate in questions or answers.

Answer (score 3):

Meh, if you want to go nuts.  In this case I don't see the need.  There are certainly worse cases.

As an example of things going the opposite way, here's one of my all-time favorites:
[**What's the difference between java and javascript?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java/245073#245073)

Same sentiment toward Java, but currently at <del>147</del> 148 upvotes (including mine, and now earlz).  Sure it torks some people off, but you get that within any (viable) community.

Comment: I *wondered* who'd been up-voting that...

Comment: @Shog I'd give it another except they seem to be hesitant on giving people extra voting power around here.

Answer (score 1):

Per the usual, insults and epithets should infect and multiply through *comments*, not the questions themselves.  Then again, is it worth edit-warring with someone who feels the need to call software names?